# How do you pull an integer from a specific location in a bidimensional arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

If I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s say "biglist".

```
[[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[5,1,2],[6,4,7],[7,1,2]]
```

How could I tally all of the 1's in the first row (so 1 4 5 6 7, total of one 1), and the same for the second etc?

I  lost on this so any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: a nested for-loop over all dimensions of your list can count each appearance

Comment: @gary just use 2 for loops, 1st loop iterates all the rows. 2nd loop iterate all the columns and check if any of columns value =1. if equals 1, count the one's and continue the row loop for next row

Comment: Yes I could do this but I want it to scale (the example I gave is miniscule), and I may be looking for other values in other rows)

Comment: @GaryJones dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
//...add your integer to the list

ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if(i == 2 || i == 3) //for instance if you want to exclude certain sublists in your list 
        continue;

    ArrayList<Integer> ints = list.get(i);
    if(ints.size() > 0)
        newList.add(ints.get(0 /* 0 or whatever part of inner list you want */));
}
```

Comment: This would be perfect if there was a way I could limit it to only be from certain rows

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getElements(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bigList, int columnIndex){
    ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for ( ArrayList<Integer> al : bigList ){
        resultList.add(al.get(columnIndex));
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

**NOTE:** I say *columnIndex* because I see your `bigList` as a matrix.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is as specified an arrayList of arrayLists

Answer (score 0):

> How could I tally all of the 1's in the first row (so 1 4 5 6 7, total of one 1), and the same for the second etc?

You can count the number of times you see a particular number in a row using something like:

```
int intWeAreLookingFor = 1;
int rowNumber=0;
for(ArrayList list: biglist){

    int numOfHits=0;
    rowNumber++;
    for(Integer i: list){

        if(i.equals(intWeAreLookingFor)){
            numOfHits++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printLine("The number '"+intWeAreLookingFor
        +"' was counted "+numOfHits+" times in row "+rowNumber+".");
}
```

For your sample array `[[1,2,3],[4,3,2],[5,1,2],[6,4,7],[7,1,2]]`, this would print out:

```
The number '1' was counted 1 times in row 1.
The number '1' was counted 0 times in row 2.
The number '1' was counted 1 times in row 3.
The number '1' was counted 0 times in row 4.
The number '1' was counted 1 times in row 5.
```